# How to show checkbox disabled for some rows in Vaadin Grid when using <vaadin-grid-selection-column>

Tags: vaadin-grid

My Polymer custom element has a Vaadin grid with say 10 rows. 
It allows selection of rows using vaadin-grid-selection-column, which renders checkboxes bound to the selection state of the grid on every row.

I need to:

- allow selection of say only 8 rows based on some condition.
- disallow selection for the balance 2 rows (either not show the checkbox or show it as disabled).

I am not sure if

```
<vaadin-grid-selection-column auto-select></vaadin-grid-selection-column>
```

can be conditioned in any way to achieve the result.
I appreciate any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own checkboxes in a renderer function. Check similar issue and solution in [How to hook data-grid events in parent lit-element component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892511/how-to-hook-data-grid-events-in-parent-lit-element-component)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes